# Printing dictionary using json.dumps in web2py

Tags: python, json, web2py

Can we directly print dictionary using json.dumps (testdictionary) in view of web2py. Returning test dictionary from the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, though by default the text will be escaped, so to avoid that, use `XML()`.

```
{{=XML(json.dumps(testdictionary))}}
```

Actually, might be cleaner to call `json.dumps` in the controller.